# ADODB not loading with .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic, com, adodb

1. I have two .NET assemblies COM_BLL.dll and COM_DAL.dll
2. BLL calls DAL which connects to the database and does what it needs to do
3. BLL is registered as a COM component
4. ASP pages use COM services to instantiate BLL classes and in turn get ADODB.RecordSet as return value
5. ASP.NET pages directly instantiate .NET classes in BLL and in turn get ADODB.RecordSet as return value

(4) is working fine but (5) is not. This is the exception message and stacktrace:

```
Could not load type 'ADODB.ParametersToInternalParametersMarshaler' from assembly 'COM_DAL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=279ed9c541abbe53'.
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.CreateCustomMarshalerHelper(IntPtr pMD, Int32 paramToken, IntPtr hndManagedType)
   at ADODB._Command.get_Parameters()
   at COM_DAL.AccountsMngr.ER_SessionMasterQuery(Int32 var1, Int32 Var2, String Var3, String Var4, Int32 Flag)
```

Comment: It might help if you showed some code, but if you want to use COM objects in aspx pages you need to use `AspCompat=true` in the `@Page` tag.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/zwk9h2kb(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change property for the ADODB reference:

- Solution Explorer > Project > References > ADODB > r-click >
  properties.
- Set Embed Interop Types = False.